# Authenticate User In Third Party Invoked WebHook

Tags: php, security, session, authentication, webhooks

I have a setup in which

1. the user may or may not log on to my site,
2. the user submits a form to a 3rd party service, and
3. the 3rd party service does its thing, then invokes a "webhook" on my site, forwarding all `$_POST` data.

So, to illustrate:

```
    +---------------------+         +---------------------------+
    | mysite.com/form.php |-------->| thirdparty.com/submit.php |
    +---------------------+         +---------------------------+
                                                  |
                                                  v
                                    +---------------------------+
                                    |   mysite.com/webhook.php  |
                                    +---------------------------+
```

**If the user was logged on at the time of submitting the form, then how can I tell and authenticate this fact in the webhook?**

For example, I could naively set a hidden field,

```
<input type="hidden" name="loggedOn" value="true" />
```

But anyone can spoof that.  I thought I might pass through the user's password hash,

```
<input type="hidden" name="passwordHash" value="$2a$08$Lg5XF1Tt.X5TGyfb43vBBeEFZm4GTXQhKQ6SY6emkcnhAGT8KfxFS" />
```

Effectively making the webhook "log in" again, but this can't be correct, as it would expose the user's password hash to the client-side.

I think there must be a better way to do this using session mechanics but I'm new to sessions.  Perhaps I'm missing the appropriate vocabulary?  Would someone guide me in the right direction?  Thanks!

---

**EDIT:**

After further research I believe the correct method is to set a hidden form field `sid` to the session id, `session_id()`, in order to pass it to the webhook, which in turn will use the session id to continue the session, `session_id($_POST['sid']); session_start();`.  My question is now whether this is the canonical (and secure) solution.

Comment: I would love to have a definitive answer from someone who's had to implement this "in the field." I would like to know not only _a way_, but _the best_ or _most widely accepted_ way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using session ID is good for keeping track of who made requests and provide some security protection.

You could also consider making each request to the third party contain:

- A **nonce** to detect replay
- **Timestamp** to detect old requests
- A [digital-signature](/questions/tagged/digital-signature) or [hmac](/questions/tagged/hmac) sent with each request. You would sign/hash any values that *might* be tampered with and verify these values in the **webhook**

Comment: Thanks! From what you said alone I wasn't quite convinced at the time, but Robbie's answer helped elucidate some of your points. I'm accepting your answer because I now realize it was the first to have the right idea; though I'm awarding the bounty to Robbie who, for me personally, fully resolved my concerns.

Comment: Thanks @acheong87. I think Robbie's answer is great too.

Answer (score 3):

A user's SessionID is known to the user anyway, and can be sniffed by man-in-the-middle approaches anyway. So if you're concerned that security can get "hacked" (and you can't go to SSL) then you would implement IP tracking, agent tracking etc. All details that can be spoofed or faked, and may even change mis-session (albeit rarely, except IP's on mobile) but it's an extra layer to add.

So the basic solution will be for you to create a session_id, pass as part of the form and then use it as you/Steve propose.

You can't use IP or Agent headers as these are lost. So you need to look at what you can use.

In increasing order of complexity, but security:

1. Does the thirdparty.com for pass on any data to you, other that the post? Check the headers; you may find they pass originiating IP, originating referrer or agent. You could use those as the simplest line of defence - they should match the original data (that you can store in a session).
2. When you create the form on your site, create another Unique ID and store in the session. Pass that in a hidden field as well to the form, when you get back the form data from "thirdparty.com" you can check the unique ID matches that on the session. Then remove the uniqueID from the session, meaning it can only be used once. (This is the NONCE pd40 refers to in his answer.)
3. If you can use javascript then trap the on submit, also send the details to your server. Your server will already have the details in the session. When "thirdparty.com" comes back to you, call up the session and check the details match. (If you don't want to  store all the details in the session, you could MD5 it - the MD5 should match on return). You can also timestamp this - if you don;t hear back within 60 seconds then something's goen a bit slow [adjust timestamp to your needs, but be generous].
4. However, my preferred (and the one we use) is to have your own server receive the form data, then generate the POST request to thirdparty.com using Curl. No actual need for the webhook - you just check the response before continuing processing yourself - the user never realises a third party is invovled and the interaction is between yourself and the server.

Also, if you're really worried, log any calls you consider "invalid". You'll find that users try to hack things a few times before they get it right - so NEVER reveal that you've identified them as a hacker (unless there's a chance of a false-positive; so be careful on this) and log. If you get 5 invalid requests from one IP (for example) then you can assume all subsequent requests from that IP are dodgy, even if good. Keep a log so you cna monitor.

Final note: SSL is always best, if you can implement it.

Hopefully that gives you an idea of the options you can implement.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer!

Comment: I am accepting pd40's answer as he had the right idea first, but didn't quite convince me, but giving you the bounty as you definitively quelled my uncertainties.

Comment: Thanks - and very fair. If only all users were as thoughtful.

Answer (score 0):

This would be easier if you had your user sessions stored in a database.  Sure, anyone could pass that form(spoof it), but if, on triggering your 'webhook', you checked the sessions table for a valid session key, you would be good to go.

Comment: I just came across the idea of passing session id's. Are you recommending that I store session id's in a database table in addition to passing the session id? Given that PHP would store session id's on the server side, what added benefit is there to storing them in a database table too?

Comment: If they are in a database you can do this:
`<input type="hidden" name="session" value="session id" />`

Then you can pass that with your form and when third party site sends the data back you can check the session id it sends to see if the user is logged in(in the database)

Comment: I guess my question is: why store it in the database at all?  The server should already know whether a session id is valid or not.  I'd like to know what added advantage there is to your method.

Comment: There's no actual way to track who made the request unless you're storing that information somewhere.  Unless you're keeping track of all of the users logged in somewhere there's no way to tell who actually sent the request.

Comment: I agree; but I thought that _that_ is what a PHP Session does: it stores session data for you, albeit temporarily.  So again, I don't see the use of a database here.  I can get the session id via ``session_id()``, I can set a hidden field to this session id, I can retrieve this session id in the webhook to set it ``session_id($_GET['sid'])``, and I can continue to session via ``session_start()``. No database necessary. My question however is (or has evolved to become): Is this the appropriate method, and is it secure?